# where does defined the Table 'test.sphinx_test_file'?

Tags: python, django

look the end line:ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test.sphinx_test_file' doesn't exist")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.finish_response()

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 319, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 374, in __iter__
    self._iterator = iter(self._container)

  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\djangosphinx\models.py", line 240, in __iter__
    return iter(self._get_data())

  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\djangosphinx\models.py", line 404, in _get_data
    self._result_cache = list(self._get_results())

  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\djangosphinx\models.py", line 570, in _get_results
    queryset = dict([(', '.join([unicode(getattr(o, p.attname)) for p in pks]), o) for o in queryset])

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 106, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 692, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 238, in iterator
    for row in self.query.results_iter():

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 287, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue

ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test.sphinx_test_file' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `syncdb` after adding the app (I'm guessing the app is named `sphinx`) to your settings.py?

Comment: yes ,it is named sphinx,but i do the 'python manage.py syncdb' already

Comment: Did you go into your MySQL shell and check if the table actually exists? If it's there, my next step would be to run `python manage.py reset sphinx` (caution - this will throw away all data stored in models defined by the `sphinx` app).